# NoReverseMatch at / list

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I tried get dynamic link

Error:

> NoReverseMatch at /
>
> Reverse for 'new_single' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found.
>   1 pattern(s) tried: ['single/']

Code:
view:

```
{% for new in news %}

    {{ new.id }}
     <h2><a href="{% url 'new_single' pk=new.id %}">{{ new.title }}</a></h2>
{% endfor %}
```

urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.news_list, name='news_list'),
    url(r'single/<int:pk>', views.new_single, name="new_single"),
]
```

views:

```
def new_single(request,pk):
    new=get_object_or_404(News,id=pk)
    return render(request,"news/news_single.html",{"new":new})
```

Comment: Did you define a `namespace` in the `urls.py`?

Comment: Hold on, you defined a path-pattern, in a `url` function. You mix up two syntaxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing two syntax variants to specify patterns. Since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0) there are two ways to specify URL patterns: with [**`path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#path), and with [**`re_path(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re-path) for regular expressions-like patterns (an alias is [**`url(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#url)).

You however mix the two. You can use the two concurrently, but you need to specify *per* `urlpatterns` entry the correct one:

```
#  app/urls.py

from django.urls import path, re

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.news_list, name='news_list'),
    path('single/<int:pk>/', views.new_single, name="new_single"),
]
```