# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-templates, atom-editor

I've been trying to get this app to work, I run: python manage.py runserver - & everything was fine, I was able to see the website, login as a superuser, make a comment, however in trying to view the post I started to get an error. Now, if I just go to the site, i get an error. I get this error message:

```
 File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/envs/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 685, in _reverse_with
_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['
post/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'post_detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>\\d+)$']
```

The browser highlights this line as the problem(it is in my base.html page shown below. This link is something I pasted from bootstrap cdn (the link is from 2 years ago). Th entire base.html is given below):

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
11
```

I found a link that may be applicable to my problem here:
[NoReverseMatch at / list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52136598/noreversematch-at-list)
where he says:

```
You are mixing two syntax variants to specify patterns. Since django-2.0 there are two ways to specify URL patterns: with path(..) [Django-doc], and with re_path(..) [Django-doc] for regular expressions-like patterns (an alias is url(..) [Django-doc]).

You however mix the two. You can use the two concurrently, but you need to specify per urlpatterns entry the correct one:

#  app/urls.py

from django.urls import path, re

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.news_list, name='news_list'),
    path('single/<int:pk>/', views.new_single, name="new_single"),
]
```

but I don't know how to apply this to my application. It might be relevant as I am following a tutorial that was made 2 years ago and is using an older version of python, i think 1. something, whereas I am using 3.8.. any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm stuck.

mysite/blog/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
    url(r'^about/$',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$',views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name='post_remove'),
    url(r'^drafts/$',views.DraftListView.as_view(),name='post_draft_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$',views.add_comment_to_post,name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/approve/$',views.comment_approve,name='comment_approve'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$',views.comment_remove,name='comment_remove'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/publish/$',views.post_publish,name='post_publish'),
]
```

mysite/mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^silk/', include('silk.urls', namespace='silk')),
    url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'}),
]
```

mysite/blog/templates/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.urls import reverse
# Create your models here.

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)



    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approved_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
#        return reverse("post_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post',related_name='comment',on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approved_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

mysite/blog/templates/blog/base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Blog</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Medium style editor -->
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/medium-editor/latest/css/medium-editor.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Russo+One" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body class="loader">

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default techfont custom-navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><<a class='navbar-brand bigbrand' href="{% url 'post_list'%}">My blog</a></li>
          <li><<a href="{%url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
          <li><<a href="http://www.github.com">Github</a></li>
          <li><<a href="http://www.linkedin.com"</a>linkedin</li>
        </ul>

        <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
          {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li>
            <<a href="{% url 'post_new' %}">New Post</a>

          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="{% url 'post_draft_list' %}">Drafts</a>

          </li>
          <li>
            <<a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a>

          </li>
          <li>
            <a> Welcome: {{user.username}}</a>

          </li>
            {% else%}
            <li><<a class='nav navbar-right' href="{%url 'login'%}"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></span></a></li>

          {%endif %}

        </ul>



      </div>

    </nav>
    <!-- Content block -->
    <div class="content container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="blog_posts">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}

          </div>


        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

mysite/blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from blog.models import Post,Comment
from blog.forms import PostForm,CommentForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                    DetailView,CreateView,
                                    UpdateView,DeleteView)
# Create your views here.

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'about.html'

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    model = Post

#delete post
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')

#unpublished drafts

class DraftListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/login'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')


########################

@login_required
def post_publish(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    post.publish
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=pk)

@login_required
def add_comment_to_post(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = post
            comment.save()
            return redirect('post_detail',pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
        return render(request,'blog/commment_form.html',{'form':form})

@login_required
def comment_approve(request,pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment,pk=pk)
    comment.approve()
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=comment.post.pk)

@login_required
def comment_remove(request,pk):
    comment_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail',pk=post_pk)
```

mysite/mysite/settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'blog/templates/blog')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+$0zreau)2tit=6_^(v56@!z1*%*j%x^9mul40b-@#xlt*e9s1'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'silk',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR , 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

mysite/blog/templates/blog/post_draft_list.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{%block content %}
  {% for post in posts %}
<div class="post">
  <p class='date'>created: {{ post.created_date|date:'d-m-Y'}}</p>
  <h1><<a href="{%url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{post.title}}</a></h1>
  <p>{{post.text|truncatechars:200}}</p>

</div>
  {%endfor%}

{% endblock%}
```

mysite/blog/templates/blog/post_list.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{%block content %}
<div class="centerstage">
  {% for post in post_list%}
  <div class="post">
    <h1><a href="{%url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk%}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
    <div class="date">
      <p>Published on: {{post.published|date:"D M Y"}}</p>

    </div>
    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post_pk %}">Comments: {{post.approve_comments }}</a>
  </div>
  {%endfor%}
</div>

{% endblock%}
```

mysite/blog/templates/blog/post_detail.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{%block content %}

  <h1 class="posttitle loader">{{post.title}}</h1>
  {% if post.published_date %}
    <div class="date postdate">
      {{ post.published_date}}

    </div>
  {%else %}
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'post_publish' pk=post.pk %}">Publish</a>
  {%endif %}

  <p class='postcontent'>{{ post.title|safe|linebreaksbr}}</p>

  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a class='btn btn-primary' href="{% url 'post_edit' pk=post.pk%}">
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>

    </a>
    <a class='btn btn-primary' href="{% url 'post_remove' pk=post.pk%}">
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>

    </a>
  {%endif%}

  <hr>
  <a class=btn btn-primary btn-comment href="% url 'add_comment_to_post' pk=post.pk%">Add comment</a>

  <div class="container">
    {%for comment in post.comments.all %}
    <br>
      {%if user.is_authenticated or comment_approved_comment %}
        {{comment.created_date}}
        {% if not comment_approved_comment%}
          <a class='btn btn-primary' href="{% url 'comment_remove' pk=comment.pk%}">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span>
          </a>
          <a class='btn btn-primary' href="{% url 'comment_approve' pk=post.pk%}">
            <<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>
          </a>
        {%endif %}

        <p>{{comment.text|safe|linebreaks}}</p>
        <p>Posted by: {{comment.author}}</p>
      {%endif %}
      {%empty %}
      <p>no comments</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

{% endblock%}
```

new errors traceback:

when I hit drafts I get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/drafts/

Django Version: 3.1.1
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 142, in get
    self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 35, in get_queryset
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured at /drafts/
Exception Value: DraftListView is missing a QuerySet. Define DraftListView.model, DraftListView.queryset, or override DraftListView.get_queryset().
```

and then when I hit 'add comment' I get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/comment/

Django Version: 3.1.1
Python Version: 3.8.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Template loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:
    * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/homepage/Desktop/My_Django_Stuff/blog_project/mysite/blog/templates/blog/blog/commment_form.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/blog/commment_form.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/blog/commment_form.html (Source does not exist)
    * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/homepage/Desktop/My_Django_Stuff/blog_project/mysite/blog/templates/blog/commment_form.html (Source does not exist)



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/homepage/Desktop/My_Django_Stuff/blog_project/mysite/blog/views.py", line 71, in add_comment_to_post
    return render(request,'blog/commment_form.html',{'form':form})
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
    template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
  File "/Users/homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /post/1/comment/
Exception Value: blog/commment_form.html
```

Comment: now I'm getting this error: ""GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 4316"-its new & 'm not sure what it means

Comment: Also getting this in the error message in Chrome: Python Path: 
['/Users/Homepage/Desktop/My_Django_Stuff/blog_project/mysite',
 '/Users/Homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python38.zip',
 '/Users/Homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8',
 '/Users/Homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/Homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/Users/Homepage/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aeosa']

Comment: It looks as if `{% url 'post_detail' pk=post_pk %}` (with an underscore) should be `{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}` (with a dot) in `mysite/blog/templates/blog/post_list.html`. Please show the full traceback when you ask questions - at the moment, I can't tell which URL the error is occurring on, so I'm guessing which template is causing the problem.

Comment: yes, I had fixed that issue & replaced the _ with a dot but that didn't fix the issue. I posted the traceback. thank you.

Comment: Please use the *Switch to copy-and-paste view* button to make the traceback more readable. And include the full error message. To debug the problem, you need to know which template the error is occurring in, and to get that, the url from the error message helps you figure out which view is causing the problem.

Comment: Note you have `{% url 'post_detail' ... %}` twice in the template. Make sure you use `post.pk` in both places. After changing it, make sure to save changes, check in/push/pull changes, and restart the Django server so that you are definitely running the code you think you are.

Comment: i replaced pk=post_pk with pk=post.pk in three places in views.py and post_list.html - and now I am getting a new error, which says: "AttributeError at /
'Post' object has no attribute 'comments'  --- idk where the "Switch to copy-and-paste view" button is, do u want me to just copy and paste the  full traceback? i'll paste the new error traceback

Comment: i figured out how to Switch to copy-and-paste view and posted it - thank you for your help.

Comment: The switch to copy and paste link is on the yellow error page, use the search page option in your browser if you can’t find it.

Comment: Anyway, the traceback says the problem is `self.comments` in the `Post` model. That’s because you have `related_name='comment'` Instead of `related_name='comments'` in the foreign key.

Comment: finally that worked!!! thank you so much!

Comment: however now I am getting new errors when I try to click on 'add comment' and  'drafts', it says: ImproperlyConfigured at /drafts/
DraftListView is missing a QuerySet. Define DraftListView.model, DraftListView.queryset, or override DraftListView.get_queryset(). and for add comments it says: TemplateDoesNotExist at /post/1/comment/
blog/commment_form.html - how are you determining the source of the problem in copy and paste view?

Comment: i fixed it all, i can close this one now